# Custom font in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts

Ok,

using a custom font since 3.2 is pretty straightforward:

Load the font in resources bundle, specify it's name in plist and there you go, you can use is in a text field with [textField setFont...].

The thing is, i want to replace the font in every part of my app, say the navigation bar so it gets complicated, because it seems i have to replace every component with a custom one in order to set the font.

Is there any way to let the bloody thing know that i want the default font replaced with a custom one, in one step? Not in every bar item, and so...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a category on `UIFont` which redefines

```
+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size {
    return [self fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:size];
}

+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size {
    return [self fontWithName:@"YourBoldFontName" size:size];
}
```

to return your custom font.

As pointed by Jonathan in the comments, it may also change the status bar font (I can't verify at the moment). I don't know if Apple would accept this behavior (redefining methods is OK but modifying the default UI isn't IMHO).

Subclassing `UIFont` wouldn't be sufficient because labels and others would still use the UIFont class by default.

Comment: Note that this will also replace the font on the status bar (the clock, etc.) in more recent versions of the OS. So be warned!

Comment: Damn! I'm not so sure to do this, i even read that you can get rejected from the App Store. As with this solution, any tips on the implementation? I redefined systemFontOfSize and called it in viewDidLoad and nothing changes (i even tried making UIFont the superclass of a CustomFont and well, even worst: also nothing).

Comment: If it changes the status bar font too, it's unlikely to be approved :/ Still I don't see how it could be achieved without a category.

Comment: So now it sounds like a six-of-one, half-dozen of another: use the global OS font and subclass for the various instances where you want a custom font, or override the global font and special-case the various instances where you want the OS font...

Comment: That's exactly what i want @fbreteto, but how can i achieve it?